# can't get c++ file to be readable infile.good()

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program and the first time it runs it creates and writes to a file and later in the program its supposed to read from that text file but the good() returns false. if I run the program a second time it will read and write perfectly.

```
while(!done) {    //loop thats not supposed to end 
//code that has nothing to do with file
infile.seekg(0,ios::beg);   
while(infile.good() && !infile.eof()) {
//reads file line by line
}
ofstream file(fileName, ios::app);
file << s+"\n";
file << m+"\n";
file.close();
```

it always writes fine but the first time I run the program and the text file is new later the program will not go into this while

if I close the program and run it again it'll go into the while and work perfectly I can't figure it out any help would be very much appreciated. I've tried putting

```
if(!infile.good()){ 
ofstream file(fileName) 
}
```

at the beginning of the file but that doesn't do anything but create the file earlier in the program and still have same problem. this is my first c++ program and its a big grade.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please create the smallest possible program that demonstrates your problem, then copy-paste that program in its entirety into your question. I estimate that you could reproduce your problem in 15-20 lines of code. See http://sscce.org for more info on this debugging technique.

Comment: I'm betting you're leaving an open handle to the file in the write that prevents the read from working; and the second time around the write doesn't happen so the read works.

Comment: You should never use `.good()` or `.eof()` as a loop condition. Doing so almost always produces a buggy program. I can't know if that is *the* problem here, but it certainly will produce *some* problem.

Comment: what should i use instead of good() and eof()? they work perfect second time i run program when there's text already in the file

Comment: If you're reading lines, the idiomatic approach would be: `while (std::getline(std::cin, line))`

Comment: Where do you open `infile`?

Comment: while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) isnt this for recieving lines from keyboard? im trying to read lines from text file. and theres no infile.open() or infile.close()

Comment: i think its a problem with .good() if the program starts with .good() being false it won't switch to true

Comment: thanks i figured it out had to put ifstream infile( fileName ); in the while loop I had it at the very top

Comment: It's the same thing. You just use the other stream instead of cin.

Answer (score 0):

After hittig end of file on your infile you have to call infile.clear() to clear the EOF bit.